# Mongoid, find models which name contains string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have my Mongoid model that has this method:

```
def self.search_by_name(sub_string)
   self.where(name: "/#{sub_string}/")
end
```

My model has `name` field which is String and `sub_string` is taken from my searchbar. Routing is ok, searchbar takes `sub_string`, but when I run this code:

```
@partners = Partner.search_by_name(params[:sub_string])
```

It gets nothing. `@partners` is empty and my table shows nothing even if there is models that actually has that `sub_string` in their names. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should try the following modification to `where`: `self.where(name: "/#{sub_string}/i")` which will try to find by name with case insensitive mode. Would that be the case for you?

Comment: Still found nothing. I have tried `/.*#{sub_string}.*/`. Not working too, found nothing

Comment: Try changing it to: `self.where(name: /#{sub_string}/i)` - I overlooked that you used quotes before, and just blindly copied your code...

Comment: Yep, just remove quotes, otherwise the mongoid searching for string, not for regexp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to just remove quotes from `where` statement and it worked.

Thanks for Pawel and Yevgeniy

Comment: Nice :) i was looking for exactly this. Thank you for answering your own question to us! Useful!